# UIPopovercontroller resizes after pushing a new View controller to the navccontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a Popovercontroller where I have a table view and a detail disclosure button. On tap of the button I need to drill down to the next level.

I need to give the user a consistent width.

I set self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(1024,768);//max number
in the viewDidLoad n ViewWillAppear of the the View COntroller to be pushed. But, even then it resizes to a random width may be 600. Any one has/solved this issue?

[Original WIdth](http://img860.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110406at432.png/)

[Width after pushing a new VC](http://img703.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110406at432.png/)

Comment: Hi, i am also facing same problem.. you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Apple updated the docs on this property since you posted your question.  Now, according to the UIViewController docs for the contentSizeForViewInPopover property:

"The recommended width for popovers is 320 points. If needed, you can return a width value as large as 600 points, but doing so is not recommended."